# Estimating probability of an event at multiple points in time

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, survival, conditional-probability

I have Machine learning Model which estimates the `churn probability in the next 6 months , for a given customer`.

Is there any mathematical way to estimate the following -

```
1)Estimate the probability of the event(churn) happening in the next 1 month.
2)Estimate the probability of the event(churn) happening in the next 12 months.
```

The model currently is a decision tree model.

Kindly let me know if any clarifications is required.
Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not without making some assumptions. Can you change the model or build a new one?

Comment: Unfortunately building a new model is out of scope , although we could make some assumption though @user2974951

Comment: assuming the churn is at constant rate then p_surv_12 months = (p_surv_6m)^2 and p_surv_1m=(p_surv_6m)^(1/6). where p_surv = 1-p_churn. (and obviously its a big assumption)

Comment: (in future I would recommend building a discrete survival model. build single model to estimate churn of each month.)